# How do I get an Evolve Mars TV Tuner working?

Tags: dvb-t

I have only one question, can I use a DVB-t tunner there? I have a DVB- t tunner [Evolve](http://www.alza.sk/evolve-mars-d198735.htm) and I would like to use it in the Ubuntu system.

- My questions are : Is it possible?
- Is there any driver for it?
- Can you plese help me with that?
- Which program I have to use to use it?

Because I have to have a dual boot system with Windows only because of this in case of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, with kernel > 3.3 ( kernel 3.5 is currently available in backport package `linux-generic-lts-quantal` ): see http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/ITE_IT9135. In short: you need to download the firmware from http://www.ite.com.tw/uploads/firmware/v3.6.0.0/dvb-usb-it9135.zip, unzip, and then

```
dd if=dvb-usb-it9135.fw ibs=1 skip=64 count=8128 of=dvb-usb-it9135-01.fw
dd if=dvb-usb-it9135.fw ibs=1 skip=12866 count=5817 of=dvb-usb-it9135-02.fw
```

Copy the two resulting .fw files to /lib/firmware ; replug device. You should see `/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0` show up (along with messages in `dmesg`); then just fire up Kaffeine and it will work (or whatever app you use to watch TV on your computer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

I found a blog and the tittle is **"Installing the USB tuner DVB-T Evolve Mars in Linux"**
The [blog](http://blogiksa.myftp.org/2011/08/29/instalacja-tunera-usb-dvb-t-evolve-mars-w-linuksie/) is not an English,but you can translate it to the English language with [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com.ar/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=es-419&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://blogiksa.myftp.org/2011/08/29/instalacja-tunera-usb-dvb-t-evolve-mars-w-linuksie/&act=url).

Perhaps you can try to follow the blog's steps,and for the test you can try this in a Virtual Machine **(VirtualBox)**"just for security".
I recommend you to *"copy"* the commands from the original blog and not for the translated one, because the commands are changed. *(I guess for the google translate tool).*

So, in my opinion you can use the translated blog to understand and for copy command use the orginal and see if it works.

Hope this will helpful.